# can't integrate our application with Google assistant using Dialogflow

Tags: php, android, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I can't integrate our application with Google assistant using Dialogflow.

We created an account on "Google actions"

We implemented Oauth2.0 in our server. It is working and meeting the standards mentioned here : 
https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-code-flow

We added our authorization links.
According to documentation mentioned here : 
https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking

We added in dialogflow account fulfillment linked to our server and we enabled Google assistant

we use the simulator of google assistant for testing.
Everytime it responds with "It looks like your App account is not linked yet. App left the conversation"

This link is requested and we repeat the request and we change the scope .
But still account not linked.
Please Advise about the missing part.

The google assistant simulator is calling this uri : 
URI : MY_AUTHORIZE_URI?response_type=code&client_id=XXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/APPLICATION_NAME&scope=username+password&state=Cs4CQUxWM2ROVHU4dVdvU..

My URI is responding with (username or password is not valid) because  the send data is "username password". The google assistant replies with "It looks like your app_name account is not linked yet.".

Comment: Can you provide examples of what the OAuth transaction looks like (both what you are getting and what you are sending to Google), removing sensitive information? Is there anything in your logs to indicate what the auth server is doing? How are you triggering the account linking? Can you show a screen shot of the simulator while testing, excluding any information? Are you going to the auth URL shown in the simulator as part of the process?

Comment: I am providing 2 URIs to google linking (Auth and token)

The /auth  URI can create authorization code
The /token URI can create or refresh the access token according to the request

When google assistant runs "Talk to x application" it requests an authorization code and I can find it in database, but it doesn't request the access token. it doesn't compelete the cycle. It is supposed for google assistant to call for an authorization code then google assistant can use it to get access token and refresh token.

Simulator is always telling that "application is not linked"

Comment: Most of that described what should be happening, and a little more about what didn't happen. Can we see examples of the requests and responses that are working? And answering some of the other questions I posed? You're not really providing enough information to help us diagnose the problem. (Updating the question is better than answering in the comments.)

Answer (score 0):

You've defined action in google console and that action or name would appear in

1. Long press on home button
2. Click on right upper corner icon
3. Click on Setting
4. Click on Home Control
5. Click on plus icon to add devices
6. Check your 'action or name from the list and click on it and it will say you to re-login. that's it.

Now you've linked your account.